# How to setup MediatR mock in a theory to expect a type passed as a parameter?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq, mediatr

I’m building an ASP.Net Core API following the CQRS pattern. Most of my controllers have identical structures and as a result, I have a lot of repetitive code in my unit tests. I want to avoid that by writing a theory to test all action methods in a controller for returning an error response.

Here is the theory:

```
[Theory]
[MemberData(nameof(TestingData))]
public void ControllerMethod_Returns_ErrorResponse(Type expectedMediatrResponseType, string methodName, object[] parameters)
{
    var expectedQueryResponse = BuildExpectedQueryErrorResponse(expectedMediatrResponseType);

    MediatorMock.Setup(e => e.Send(It.IsAny<It.IsAnyType>(), CancellationToken.None))
        .ReturnsAsync(expectedQueryResponse);
    
    InvokeMethod(_categoriesController.Object, methodName, parameters);
    
    _categoriesController.Protected().Verify("HandleErrorResponse", Times.Once(), GetErrorsFromResult(expectedQueryResponse));
}
```

In the ideal case, I’d like to replace It.IsAnyType with the type of the command passed as a parameter.
Unfortunately, the code above doesn't work and _mediator.Send(command) returns null.
Is there a way to mock MediatR to return an object of type I don’t know yet at compile time? Or, is what I’m trying to achieve conceptually wrong?

Here’s the data I’m passing to the theory:

```
public static IEnumerable<object[]> TestingData => new List<object[]>
{
    new object[]
    {
        typeof(Result<Category>),
        "UpdateCategory",
        new object[]{ 
            Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), 
            new CategoryRequestDTO 
            { 
                Name = "Sample name", 
                Description = "Sample long description" 
            }
        }
    }
};
```

This is the `BuildExpectedQueryErrorResponse` method:

```
public object BuildExpectedQueryErrorResponse(Type expectedQueryResponseType)
{
    var failureMethod = expectedQueryResponseType.GetMethods().FirstOrDefault(result => 
        result.Name.Equals("Failure") && result.GetParameters().Length == 4);
    var expectedResponse = failureMethod.Invoke(expectedQueryResponseType, new object[]
    {
        ErrorCode.UnknownError, ErrorType.Unexpected, true, "Error message"
    });
    return expectedResponse;
}
```

This is the action method I’m testing:

```
[HttpPut("{id}")]
[ValidateGuid("id")]
[ValidateModel]
public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateCategory([FromRoute] string id, [FromBody] CategoryRequestDTO category)
{
    var command = _mapper.Map<UpdateCategoryCommand>(category, options => 
        options.AfterMap((_, cmd) => cmd.Id = Guid.Parse(id)));
    
    var response = await _mediator.Send(command);

    if (response.IsError) return HandleErrorResponse(response.Errors);

    return NoContent();
}
```

The response is always of the type `Result<T>`. The `HandleErrorResponse` method is tested separately, here I only want to verify it’s been called.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the following solution:

Extracted MediatR setup into a generic method in my `BaseControllerUnitTest` class

```
public void SetupMediator<C, R>(object result) where C:IRequest<R>
{
    MediatorMock.Setup(e => e.Send<R>(It.IsAny<C>(), CancellationToken.None)).ReturnsAsync(result.As<R>());
}
```

and then I call `SetupMediator`in the theory:

```
var setupMediatorMethod = GetType().GetMethod("SetupMediator").MakeGenericMethod(command, expectedMediatrResponseType);
setupMediatorMethod.Invoke(this, new[]{ expectedQueryResponse });
```